# No se actualiza archivo descargado

Tags: vb.net

estoy publicando una base de datos en google drive y aun aplicacion en vb.net que deberia descargar dicha base de datos y guardarla en mi disco duro y desde alli trabajar, el problema es que no descarga la version actualizada de la base de datos sino que deja la base de datos anterior.
aunque la borre siempre aparece las misma anterior y no la que esta en la carpeta de google drive, es como si quedara en memoria y no descarga la version actual.

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class menuppal
Public titulo As String = "La Iglesia de Jesucristo de los Santos de los Ultimos Dias"
Private Sub menuppal_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Text = titulo
    'actualizar base de datos
    basedatos()
    'actualizar aplicacion
    aplicacion()
    'conectar a la base de datos
    conex()
    Panel1.Visible = False
End Sub
Sub aplicacion()

End Sub
Sub basedatos()
    'actualizacion de la base de datos
    'crear la carpeta de la base de datos
    Dim folderdb As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\Aplicacion SUD\Base de Datos\"
    If Directory.Exists(folderdb) Then
    Else
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderdb)
    End If
    'borrar la base de datos temporal
    Dim fileold As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\Aplicacion SUD\temp\BarrioAltaVistades.s3db"
    Dim filedb As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\Aplicacion SUD\Base de Datos\BarrioAltaVista.s3db"
    If System.IO.File.Exists(fileold) = True Then
        System.IO.File.Delete(fileold)
    End If
    'descargar la base de datos
    Try
        My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=19CeFkZtmYCXpJo6DPwuhl9WdDoBxbhDx", fileold)
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(fileold, filedb, overwrite:=True)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("No se pudo actualizar la base de Datos....", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Sistema dice")
    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub InvestigadoresToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles InvestigadoresToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Panel1.Visible = True
    invest(investigador)
End Sub

Private Sub NuevoConversoToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NuevoConversoToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Panel1.Visible = True
    invest(NuevoConv)
End Sub
Sub invest(ByVal panel As Form)
    Panel1.Controls.Clear()
    panel.TopLevel = False
    Panel1.Controls.Add(panel)
    panel.Show()

End Sub

Private Sub Panel1_Paint(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Paint

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: sera un tema del id del archivo que estas descargando? es muy probable que ese id cambie cuando actualizas el archivo.. puede ser?

Comment: la id es la misma, si utilizo en el navegador el link de descarga, descarga el archivo actualizado de google drive, pero al hacerlo con el visual basic no, descarga el otro aun cuando ya tecnicamente no existe por que se actualizó

Comment: Si lo haces en modo debug, y esperas en cada instruccion anda? Lo que puede estar pasando es que las funciones que tocan archivos no se esten llegando a ejecutar porque el sistema operativo tarda... inclusive puede que ni hayas bajado el archivo..